# How can I update a value on screen every second (for 20-30 seconds only) in the easiest way with ASP.NET Core? (I don't want to use SignalIR or AJAX)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a web page programmed with ASP.NET Core & Razor. In the binded cs file I have a C# code that is reading the CPU Load from a remote machine every second with WMI. Now what I want, when the page is loaded by the client is:
In the cshtml page the CPU value should be updated every second (for 20 seconds totaly) , so that the client should see every second the updated value on the screen. There is no more complexity on the page.
I know that SignalIR is perhaps the best solution for live data but I cannot invest that money for just this one task. I also have no knowledge about AJAX or other complex methods.
I had done the same task with php before. I used the flush method to flush every second the updated CPU Load to the screen. Before each flush I cleaned the screen object with an additional java script.
Can I do something similar with ASP.NET core and Razor? (I have to switch to asp.net core due to some reasons)

I have written this code: But this code is giving me all the 20 values after 20 seconds on the screen.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@using System.Threading;
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">

@for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{<p>CPULoad: @Model.CPU_Load_WMI</p>
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

</div>
```

Comment: *"AJAX or other complex methods"* - Making an AJAX request every second for 20 seconds to an endpoint which reads and returns this data is probably the **simplest** of any method available.  SignalR (which, where do you see it costing money?) would be more robust and certainly recommended for scenarios with high user load or where there isn't a limit of only 20 seconds.  But if we're talking about few concurrent users and the code cuts off the interval after 20 requests, 20 small AJAX requests isn't unreasonable.

Comment: if you don't use js at all can also refresh classic html way: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="25"> (in html <head>)

Comment: `but I cannot invest that money `...you can host your own instance if need be. And anyway unless you're at huge scale it's unlikely to cost more than a few $ a month for the cloud version.